# XQuartz needs opening twice since macOS 13 Ventura

Tags: ssh, x11, xquartz

Since I updated to macOS 13 Ventura, whenever I try to switch to XQuartz I have to switch twice for it to show me the window. The first time I click the icon or do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the window, the window seems open - in fact, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shows XQuartz as the first program, but the XQuartz window is still behind the rest of my windows.

It never did this before updating. Is this a known problem and if it is, is there some way of fixing it?

Update: I uninstalled and reinstalled XQuartz using homebrew but it still gives me the same problem.

Update 2: I updated XQuartz to version 2.8.4, but I'm still having the same problem

Comment: What happens if you have multiple X windows

Comment: @mmmmmm I can cycle between them without problems, but all windows have the same problem that after you first open them you have to access the window twice in a row to get it to show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved updating to macOS 13.3

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem... While I'm glad it's not just me, I can find no solution. I had a similar issue on startup with previous OS releases, where the initial (emacs) window would sometimes be on the wrong screen and hidden but that was fixable with wmctrl, and it stayed fixed until the app was closed.

Best fix for me for this issue is to use CMD-Tab to select X11, then hold CMD-Tab and press Left to reselect it.

This is incredibly annoying as I use emacs remotely, and constantly switch between that and iTerm...

Comment: I do the same, but it's really annoying. I'm considering reinstalling MacOS but I haven't yet got up the courage!

Comment: @BethLong Don't reinstall the OS. There's never any point doing that - it's on a read only partition and won't boot if it's been modified. Are you using XQuartz from the Xquartz project, or homebrew?

Comment: @benwiggy I was originally using a version I downloaded directly from the Xquartz project, but after the problem arose I reinstalled it using homebrew to see whether that would fix it, but it didn't

Comment: I noticed that this problem has been raised on the Github bug reporting system too https://github.com/XQuartz/XQuartz/issues/293